# copy huge number of files into date structured directory order

Tags: command-line, files, cp

I need to copy around 40.0000 files into date structured folders.
example file:

```
/var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring/20151209/bbbbbb_I_20151209-185841_xxxxxx_12434_89343.WAV
```

Is one of the many files I need to copy to `/home/username/logging/`

The file name has 2 variables in it that I need to use:

```
bbbbbb_I_20151209-185841_xxxxxx_12434_89343.WAV
```

`20151209` is of course the date
`12434` is the id of the user who made the file.

What I need is a script/one liner that can search in a dir for the user id.

Then create a dir with the user id in `/home/username/logging`. 
After it created the folder it needs to create a dir for every date it can find.
And place every file in to the right `userid/date` directory.
example of result dir.

```
/home/username/logging/12434/20151209/bbbbbb_I_20151209-185841_xxxxxx_12434_89343.WAV
```

I have build a one-liner for making the date dir's , but I still need to make the user id dir myself.

```
find /var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring/ -type f -name "*12434*" | sed -r 's/^.{65}//' | cut -c1-8 | xargs -I {} mkdir {} /home/username/logging/12434
```

How can I copy the right file to the right place?

Comment: Is the date always after the second _ in your file names and is the userID always before the last _ ? Are all these files `WAV` ? Are all directory names right under `...quality_monitoring/` dates or are there other dir names that are not dates ?

Comment: Yes to all of your questions. 
And all directorys under <code> ...quality_monitoring </code> are only dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `find` and `install`:

```
find /var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring -name \*.WAV -exec sh -c '
bn=${0##*/}; x=${bn%%-*}; dt=${x##*_}; y=${bn%_*}; id=${y##*_} 
install -D "$0" "/home/username/logging/${id}/${dt}/${bn}"' {} \;
```

this uses parameter expansion to extract the date: `${dt}` and the user id: `${id}` from the filename and then uses [`install`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/install-invocation.html) to copy each file to the corresponding `userID/date` directory (this is because I'm lazy) - without `install` replace the last line with:

```
dest=/home/username/logging/${id}/${dt}; mkdir -p "${dest}" && cp "$0" "${dest}"' {} \;
```

If you prefer to loop over those "date" directories and then loop over the `.WAV` files in each dir:

```
for d in /var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring/*; do
  dt=${d##*/}
  for f in $d/*.WAV; do
    bn=${f##*/}; y=${bn%_*}; id=${y##*_}
    dest=/home/username/logging/${id}/${dt}
    mkdir -p "${dest}" && cp "${f}" "${dest}"
  done
done
```

---

If you have `zsh` it's easier and shorter with `zmv` (also because `zsh` is smarter and you can nest variable expansions e.g. `${${file%_*}##*_}` would be enough to extract the user ID):

```
dtcp () {                                                                     
mkdir -p $3 && cp $1 $2 $3
}
autoload zmv
zmv -n -p dtcp '/var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring/(*)/(*).WAV' \
'/home/username/logging/${${2%_*}##*_}/$1'
```

The `(*)`s create back references that can be used in the second parameter as `$1`, `$2` etc.
Here `zmv` with `-p` executes the function `dtcp` instead of `mv`. The function creates the directory and then copies the file to the newly created directory. The arguments (not to be mistaken for the back references above) are:
`$1` : `--`
which means end of options
`$2` : `/var/public/voicelogging/quality_monitoring/(*)/(*).WAV'`
that is the file that has to be copied and
`$3` : `/home/username/logging/${${2%_*}##*_}/$1`
which is the destination
Note that `-n` stands for *dry-run*; remove it to actually run the command.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what i need, and it works like a charm!